# remove the default Cache setting in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, caching, overriding, fluent

I'm glad to set common cache for almost all the entity like the following with Fluent NHibernate:

```
    public static FluentConfiguration Create(string connStr)
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
          .Cache(x => x.UseSecondLevelCache().ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>())
          .Mappings(m =>
              {
                  m.FluentMappings
                      .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>()
                      .Conventions.Add(
                        // here the cache is set ReadWrite
                        Cache.Is(x => x.ReadWrite()),
                      );

              })
    }
```

But there is still some entities that I DO NOT want to cache them. How should I do?

```
public class ActivityMap : EntityMap<Activity>
{
    public ActivityMap()
    {
        References<User>(m => m.Executor);

        //Note: I'm not want to change the cache but REMOVE the cache!
        //Cache.ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a real solution or just a walk around that is to set the expiration=0 in the cache region node in web.config, but whatever it works.